# Set WPF Label Content based on Value of bool Dependency Property

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have a label in a WPF user control:

```
<Label Name="lblTitle"></Label>
```

In the code behind, I define a dependency property called `Customer`. Customer itself has a property called `IsNew`. I would like to bind `lblTitle.Content` so that when `IsNew == true` then it would be "Create New", and when it is `false` then the `Content` would be set to "Update" (I would do this in ASP.net by setting `lblTitle.Text = IsNew ? "Create New" : "Update";`).

What is the best way to do this?

**Edit**

Here is my declaration of the property in the code behind:

```
public Cust Customer{
    get { return (Cust)GetValue(CustomerProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CustomerProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomerProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Customer", typeof(Cust), typeof(Name_Of_Control), new UIPropertyMetadata(new Cust()));
```

Answer (score 4):

This should help you

```
<Label Name="lblTitle">
    <Label.Style>    
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="Label.Content" Value="Update" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Customer.IsNew}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Label.Content" Value="Create New" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Label.Style>
</Label>
```

Also, if you want to apply a style from your resources, you can use `BasedOn` attribute:

`<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MyLabelStyleName}" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">`

With that you'll be able to set a new content value based on `Customer.IsNew` property as well as a style for your `Label` control.

Comment: There is a missing / on the second <Label.Style>

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<Label Name="lblTitle">
    <Label.Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="Update" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Customer.IsNew}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="Create New" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Label.Style>
</Label>
```

Comment: When I do this, the content for the label stays set as "System.Windows.Style". I have checked and the Customer property is initialized properly on the page, with IsNew=true by default.

Comment: He just forgot to add `<Label.Style>` after `<Label>` tag, the code itself looks good.

Answer (score -3):

One other thing worth noting is that if your label is simply displaying text then you are better of using a TextBlock rather than a label:

http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/07/04/differences-between-label-and-textblock/